# Mongoose filter out entries that have objects with empty fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that has an array of objects.

```
{
  "data": {
    "array": [
      {
        "field 1": "blahblah",
        "field 2": "blahblah"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

so i would like to only get records in which none of the "array" element have "field 1" as an empty string.
What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: not much, I have no idea how to specify an query on array elements

Comment: Start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#arrays

Comment: I have updated the question. I need to filter out records that contains any "array" element that has a empty "field 1". So {"array":[{"field 1": ""}]} will be filtered out so will {"array":[{"field 1":"asdfsadf"}, {"field 1": ""}]}

Comment: i tried: find({"data.array":{$all:[{"$elemMatch" : {"field 1":{$ne:""}}}]}})
and it did not work :(

Comment: That seemed to work when I tried it.  What about it didn't work for you?

Comment: @JohnnyHK 's answer totally works. But just for curiosity-sake, does anyone know why my previous comment did not work? It still returned all records, including the ones that are supposed to be filtered out

Comment: It did exclude docs where 'field 1' was '' when I tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used with an array field, the `$ne` value must not match *any* array element for the document to be included, so you can simplify your query to:

```js
MyModel.find({'data.array.field 1': {$ne: ''}});
```